# Search value in a EditText

Tags: email, verification, editbox

I have a edit box in my `layout` and when user press the button for `Send Mail`to check if the value from`Edit Box` contains  `@ and .com`

```
layout code:
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:hint="Descriere"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="22dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="162dp" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Send"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

and java is empty I didn't try anything because I didn't know how to search the value in edit box

Comment: Show us your implementation and what you have tried this far.

Comment: @Mikko I've updated the question